# Why do I need to open the blah.do before it is taken by the actual program?

Tags: java, struts-1

I'm learning struts in school. I have a VERY basic hello world but there is one thing I don't seem to get right.

I have the strut form, the strut action, the main jsp(working off of the welcomeStruts.jsp), and the struts-config.xml.. which are the four files I'm working with.

Form is this:

```
public class mensaje extends org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm {
    private String message;
    public String getMessage() {
    return message;
    }
    public void setMessage (String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Action is this:

```
public class mensajeAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {
     @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
       HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws Exception {
        mensaje hellwForm = (mensaje) form;
        hellwForm.setMessage("Hello World");
        return mapping.findForward("success");
      }
}
```

The call from the jsp is like this:

```
<html:form action="/mensajeAct">
    <bean:write name="mensaje" property="message"/>
</html:form>
```

And lastly, this is what I have in the struts-config

```
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="mensaje" type="Struts.Form.mensaje"/>
    </form-beans>
    <global-forwards>
        <forward name="welcome"  path="/Welcome.do"/>
    </global-forwards>
    <action-mappings>
        <action input="/Welcome" name="mensaje" path="/mensajeAct" scope="session" type="Struts.Action.mensajeAction" validate="false"/>
        <action path="/Welcome" forward="/welcomeStruts.jsp"/>
    </action-mappings>
```

NOW... if I just go to my browser (localhost:8080/helloworld), it will NOT add the "Hello World" part of the action.
HOWEVER, if I first go in my browser to the .do  (localhost:8080/helloworld/mensajeAct.do), and then go back to the main page (localhost:8080/helloworld) it now works. And at this point after I have visited the .do once, I can make changes in netbeans, hit play, and it takes the changes.

So, question is, am I doing something wrong in struts, or could it be GlassFish playing tricks on me? I tried IE and Firefox and it behaves the same in both.

Thanks much!

Comment: Unrelated, but it's too bad your school is teaching you a framework that was EOLed some time ago. It also makes it more difficult to follow best programming practices because of the intertwining of layers.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm totally with you. Also, I wish we had better teachers too. I'm following a "tutorial" the teacher gave us.. Out of three tutorials we were supposed to follow, 2 don't work as expected.

Comment: Make 'em right and give 'em back; this accomplishes two things: it helps other current and future students, and it helps the teacher understand they should pay more attention.

Comment: Ended up trashing the original school 'tutorial'. Grabbed a couple tutorials from well known web sources, then re-did the original with the gathered knowledge. Differences I noted after doing it 'my way'
1. added an extra global forward
2. changed logic from the index.jsp
3. my understanding of the actions-forwards have definitely improved. I did them manually the second time around instead of generated by netbeans

THANKS to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `*.do` should map with the `path` in `<action-mappings>`. So `mensajeAct.do` in the url `localhost:8080/helloworld/mensajeAct.do` maps with `path="/mensajeAct"(<action input="/Welcome" name="mensaje" path="/mensajeAct" scope="session" type="Struts.Action.mensajeAction" validate="false"/>)` and it takes you to the relevant Action class(`mensajeAction` in your case)

Steps:

1. The RequestProcessor looks up for xml block with `mensajeAct.do`
2. It finds the following xml block from `struts-config.xml` `<action
   input="/Welcome" name="mensaje" path="/mensajeAct" scope="session"
   type="Struts.Action.mensajeAction" validate="false"/>`
3. It instantiates the Action class(`mensajeAction`) given in your
   `type` attribute
4. After doing necessary steps in Action class, it searches for
   `<forward name="success" path="blah.jsp"/>` in your
   `<action-mappings>` and forwards to `blah.jsp`

Comment: So, I'm forwarding back to the jsp on success?? I tried the following and it still gave me the same result. 
    <action input="/Welcome" name="mensaje" path="/mensajeAct" scope="session" type="Struts.Action.mensajeAction" validate="false">
            <forward name="success" path="/welcomeStruts.jsp"/>
    </action>

Comment: @Fredog What did u try? Ideally your `<action-mappings>` should have been `<action 
 input="/Welcome" 
 name="mensaje" 
 path="/mensajeAct" 
 scope="session" 
 type="Struts.Action.mensajeAction" 
 validate="false">
<forward
          name="success"
          path="success.jsp"
          redirect="true" />
          </action>`

Comment: Just seeing your edited comment. If you are giving a jsp name in `path`, give `path="welcomeStruts.jsp"`, use the `/`, only if you again give a `.do.` `path="/welcomeStruts.do"`. Hope you understand the difference

Comment: Also make sure your jsp is in correct path in your project

Comment: Thank you vysh. I still don't seem to be able to make it work properly. I tried with both /Welcome and "welcomeStruts.jsp" on the forward. it was a typo on what I sent.  When I first run the project, the data from /mensajeAct is not there (as in, it does not say "hello world"). If i manually open localhost:8080/helloworld/mensajeAct.do, all the consecutive times I run the project it works fine. I just don't get it

Comment: @Fredog I might start with a Struts 1 blank web app (in the archived download) or follow a different tutorial for the time being, then go back and retrofit the working demo for your own requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code in **mensajeAction** action class you forwarded to your action response to "success" servelet which is not mapped in your struts-config.xml.
As per Struts 1.0 specs it need to be mapped because for every request and response in struts the Request Processor look into struts-config.xml as it is the main Controller configuration.

hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry but, what should I map it to?

Comment: You need to try this:<forward name="success" path="yourforwardedpage.jsp"/> in your struts action mappings section

Comment: In your Action Mapping tag for the action that you need to direct its response for a jsp

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer is because the Struts 1.x framework was designed to run in a Servlet container (such as Apache Tomcat).

All Servlet containers follows the basic principle, that your web application **must** contain a `web.xml` file. For Struts to work, it follows the simple configuration like so:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>config</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `<url-pattern>` says that all URL part ending with the `.do` must be picked up by the Servlet container and call a servlet whose servlet name is `action`. This `action` is your struts `ActionServlet`. This is the actual processor which delegates responsibility to Struts `RequestProcessor` and runs your `Action` class.

This type of architecture is called the `Model View Controller` pattern and that's what Struts 1.x has been designed upon.

In essence, without a `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` in your `web.xml` file, mapping to your Struts' `ActionServlet`, your application won't be executed at all.

Comment: I do have the servlet-mapping in web.xml. It has the exact same thing you put in there. I didn't add it in the top since it is a self-generated file (including the servlet-mapping) and haven't mess with it

Comment: What I'm saying is that if these configuration didn't exist in `web.xml`, your application code will **never** be picked up at all. This is the entry point to your Struts logic. You can change the `<url-pattern>` to whatever you want and you'll see that your application URL **must** match the URL pattern in order for it to be called. In essence, your application is a "Servlet". That's the root of it all (the `<servlet-mapping>` mapping to the `<servlet-name>` which is linked to a `<servlet-class>`).